# get primary email address/contct number of facegroup group members

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have used facebook api to fetch details of group members.
using api i can fetch user first name, last name but not able to fetch email address.
 this is code

```
$member_profile = $facebook->api('/group_id/members?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,birthday');
```

Answer (score 0):

You either did not authorize with the `email` permission or the email is not confirmed in the Facebook account - it´s also possible that the user did not login with his email, afaik you can login with a phone number too. In general, you can never be 100% sure to get an email from the user.

Debug your Access Token and make sure the `email` permission shows up: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: i have used  `$fbPermissions = 'email';` in array while login. the person who logged in only his email id i can accessed. not all group members

Comment: yes. after debug i cant see email permission. what is step for email permission.

Comment: then make sure you get asked for the email permission in the authorization process, use the scope parameter correctly. hard to say anything else without your login code, you should include it in your question.